# Bluebird promise and Sequelize simulate transaction atomicity

Tags: node.js, transactions, promise, sequelize.js, bluebird

I am using bluebird.js promise and sequelize.js to emulate transactions on my site. 
Basically I try to do something in processTransactions, if everything is ok I will t.commit() the transaction, otherwise I will t.rollback() the transaction.

Also I am doing the control flow using bluebird.js promise. here is the code:

```
var processTransactions = function(transactionmain, transactionlist, t){
    // code to process transactions
};


var processtransaction = function(transaction_id)  {

  // t need to be passed in so we can choose 
  // t.commit() or t.rollback() the transaction
  sequelize.transaction(function(t){

    return Promise.resolve({}).bind({transactionmain: [...], transactionlist: [...]})
    .then(function(){
        return [this.transactionmain, this.transactionlist, t];
    })
    .spread(processTransactions)
    .then(function(){
        t.commit().success(function() {})
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        t.rollback().success(function() {})
    });

  }).error(function(err){
    t.rollback().success(function() {})
  });
};
```

My question is if I don't pass t parameter into the processTransactions then the function can execute but cannot achieve atomicity.  if I pass t then the program stops there.

Anyone know what is happening?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that simply passing `t` causes a problem or does it depend on how `t` is used in `processTransactions()`?

Comment: I don't know what you think `this` is set to in the `then` there ( in `this.trasnactiondomain`) but it's nothing meaningful. Try `Promise.resolve().bind(this).then(...`

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yes when I pass t then the program stops there.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you're right I did bind something to the promise.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem very well - if your code gets stuck then either the promise does not resolve or you have a race condition. Please consider re-reading your question from the perspective of someone who has never seen your code before - it's hard for me to understand what in particular is the problem.

Comment: got it. I will try to reduce/revise the code first!

Comment: If you were to write `... .spread(function(transactionmain, transactionlist) { /* code to process transactions */ }). ...`, then `t` doesn't need to be passed -  it will be available from the closure formed by outer function. Suggest you try this, at least for diagnosis. If it still doesn't work, then you must suspect the "process transactions" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer here... 
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1510

I think the error is because transaction is not a promise so the promise cannot work correctly.  If I use bluebird promisify the transaction function then it will work.